# Issue related to Multiline Textbox in ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am new to DevExpress Controls.

I was studing the ASPxGridView demonstration [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditForm.aspx). The notes field is a multiline TextBox. I have tried the same code and design as given in the demonstration, but I did not get a multiline TextBox for the notes field.

How can I get a multiline TextBox in as in the demonstration?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using which is not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the relevant sections of your .aspx file? Does it include `RowSpan="4"` in the EditFormSettings of the notes field?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use GridViewDataMemoColumn, which generates multi-line text box editor – ASPxMemo. Otherwise, use standalone ASPxMemo editor within the required template as it is illustrated in the http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx online demo.